# Become a (or the) ForeFlight knowledgebase?

Tags: discussion

As far as I can tell, there is no community forum / knowledge base about ForeFlight. Certainly ForeFlight itself does not host one, which is a shame. Sure you can find questions about using ForeFlight on various make/model forums, but that's absurdly inefficient. I joined Aviation.SE hoping to find that EFB savvy folks would be discussing ForeFlight here regularly. Surprise! There's not even a ForeFlight tag.

As a new community member, maybe I'm unaware of some reason that ForeFlight is not tagged or even regularly discussed here. But if there isn't one, could the community create a tag? Are there other ways we could encourage centralizing ForeFlight questions here?

**Edit**

Here are a few Aviation.SE posts that may merit a ForeFlight tag:

- [Legal requirements for electronic flight bags like Foreflight or SkyDemon](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/66465/57454)
- [What is the proper way to update the time enroute in an EFB system without the assistance of any GPS technology?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/71614/57454)
- [Where can a PDF of the TPP legend and supplemental materials be found?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25543/57454)
- [Can I fly a practice LNAV approach with an iPad?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/84584/57454)

But I think the following questions also fit the [documented](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) "within limits" user-to-user support:

- Can I add an uncharted hold to my flight plan?
- Does anyone create a performance profile for each altitude or what do you do?
- Where are the VFR sectional legends?

Note that I don't add "in ForeFlight" to the question, as it is common practice on SE to not re-state what is implied by a suitable tag.

Comment: A tag cannot be created without existing questions. It'd be preferable if you can find at least 3-5 existing questions that are specifically about ForeFlight and list them on this meta question. Otherwise, as Federico mentioned, try composing an on-topic sample question on this meta question while following the guidance on [the help center about product support](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/product-support).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. Hadn't seen that help topic before, it's a little buried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is an greement between ForeFlight and StackExchange (and even then, limitations apply), Aviation.SE is not a place where support for third party products is provided.

edit:

I looked over those questions, and imho, none of them is about Foreflight, so they should not get a "foreflight" tag.

And in terms of user-to-user support, tha page is the same for every SE (even Politics has [one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)), and we've always erred towards the side of "we don't provide product support here".

If as a community there is a desire to change this, it can be discussed, but it is not limited to foreflight or any other specific product.

Comment: I didn't say "support". I mean Q&A, just like you can ask questions concerning Linux on SO. I assume they don't have an agreement? I could be naive ...

Comment: @Ian can you make an example of a question that you have in mind that would not consitute "product support" for this app?

Comment: @Federico here is one, which I think is on-topic and not product support per se: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/legal-requirements-for-electronic-flight-bags-like-foreflight-or-skydemon

Comment: @Frederico Done!

Comment: @Ian answer updated. sorry for the delay (and it is Federico)